# Silverlight MVVM : How to do Localization in the correct way?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, localization

In normal Silverlight projects, localization in the **xaml view** is done using:

```
Text="{BindingPath=ApplicationStrings.MyNewString, Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}}"
```

My question is : how to do correct localization from labels when using the MVVM pattern?

Is this done like described [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Internationalization-Globalization-in-Silverlight-Part-5-MVVM-Approach.aspx) ?

In **xaml view**:

```
Text="{Binding LblUsername,FallbackValue='User Name'}"
```

And the **LoginViewModel.cs** class:

```
public string LblUsername
{
    get { return Resources.Username; }
}
```

Any tips here ?

---

And how about reusing the same string on multiple view/viewmodels ?
(Just imagine that I need 'Username' on multiple views.)
Does it make sense to to derive all viewmodels from a basemodel which defines all resources ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out my article on localization using MVVM.

http://cloudringer.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/localization-in-wpf-and-silverlight-with-mvvm/

There are many ways to solve the problem depending on your needs and constraints.  The approach I describe has been flexible and blendable enough to meet my needs in WPF and Silverlight on multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Well we use the

```
ApplicationStrings.MyNewString, Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}}
```

And it works fine. it's a project on the solution level and i just ref. the project into the individual projects, then i can use it as a global localization. and one "label" is only defined once.

I'm Danish so we have german, swedish, danish, english etc. translations running. If this dont help you i can provide code. But you are on the right track with option one :-)